# Additional Comments added to input

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have an excel file that was passed on to me and when I enter a number (say 154) in a cell it comes back with "comments = 154" where do i go and find where to delete that additional words. We thought it would be under conditional formatting

Comment: Do you mean when you add the number to cell and get the value is comments = 154? How about text? Do you have a screenshot? Try to clear formats.

Answer (score 0):

Check your number format.  You can set a custom format that includes text.  For example, you can have positive numbers with the text "Increase" and negative numbers with the text "Decrease" by setting the custom format to

```
$#,##0 " (Increase)";$#,##0 " (Decrease)";"-";@
```